# Add Join in ModelBuilder gives ERROR 999999

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, attribute-joins, error-999999

I'm trying to use Add Join in ModelBuilder but it keeps giving me an error message "generic error". Funny thing is, it works fine if I do one Join but I need to do several ones (about 200s or something and I want to do them at the same time of course).

I've tried Iterators and now succumbed to pasting the same simple formula in ModelBuilder several times but it still doesn't work. Of course I could do this manually but I would rather not having to do that.

I've also tried Join Field but that took 9 minutes for one of these records, it would take hours upon hours since I need to do this many times.

Is this a common problem?

This is an image of my model which outputs error message after one second or so. Some text is in Swedish "alla_lgh_sweref" are my point dataset and the polygon shapefiles are in buffer50 geodatabase.

[image]

> Error 999999: Error executing function.

So it's a generic error that doesn't say much. I just try to run the model with the Add Join tool. It works fine if I do it manually, but if I try to batch and/or model it doesn't work.

Comment: 200 joins on the same source layer or on different source layers?

Comment: Two layers, 1 point data set and then several shapefiles.

Comment: Would you be able to post a screenshot of your attempt in model builder?

Comment: I have done that now, though maybe it's hard to tell what the problem is still.

Comment: The reason `Join Field` takes longer than `Add Join` is because it's permanently adding the fields and populating values. `Add Join` is temporary.

Comment: It still takes forever though, if I do a regular join via the ToC and right-clicking its instant.

Comment: This worked for me: Try deleting the intermediate data of the model manually. To manually delete intermediate data after running a model in the ModelBuilder window, click Model menu > Delete Intermediate Data.

Try running the model again.